# How to move apps from internal storage to SD?

Tags: samsung, internal-storage

I’ve got Samsung ON5 with only 8 GB of internal storage + 32 GB SD card. I configured all photos and videos to use the SD card, which still has plenty of storage. However, the internal memory is 97% full.

Thus the question: is it possible to move apps from internal storage to SD? Is it possible to install new apps on SD?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to move apps to SD but only for some applications. To move the apps just head towards

Settings>Application Manager

Open the app which you want to move to SD and there will be an option to move it to External Storage. Just click it (Remember that you can't move your inbuilt apps to external Storage). For your 97% internal storage, just move all your things like music, photos, videos, etc., to your external storage.

Comment: Music, photos, videos -- all that is already on SD. The 97% are mostly pre-installed apps, some from Samsung, some from T-Mobile.

Comment: Then you can just simply disable the apps you don't use. And simply clear caches of all the apps